# Function does't add data to model(via serializer)

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework

Here is function I wrote, it checks field called 'url' inside 'Url1' Model and continues IF it's empty.

```
def mozs():
    getids = Url1.objects.values_list('id', flat=True)
    for id in getids:
        if Url1.objects.get(id=id).pda == None:

            authorities= {"pda": 58.26193857945012, "upa": 36.56733779379807}    
            authorities['keyword'] = id

            serializer = MozSerializer(data=authorities)

            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()  

            print "For %d we added %s" % (id, authorities)
```

Here is output:

> For 37 we added {'keyword': 37, 'pda': 58.26193857945012, 'upa': 36.56733779379807}

**But it doesn't add it.** Here is serializer:

```
class MozSerializer(serializers.Serializer):    
    keyword = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=KW.objects.all())
    pda = serializers.FloatField()
    upa = serializers.FloatField() 


    def save(self):
        keyword = self.validated_data['keyword']
        pda = self.validated_data['pda']
        upa = self.validated_data['upa']

        Url1.objects.update(pda=pda, upa=upa)
```

Comment: I think you can do all this with the query:  `Url1.objects.filter(pda__isnull=True).update(pda= 58.26193857945012, upa=36.56733779379807)`

Comment: This completely skips the serializer though, right ?

Comment: Yes, then no serializers and iteration would be needed. You can just add this 1 line in your view and do all this.